# Is there a way to find the number of cases that the Alloy Analyzer considers?

Tags: alloy

Appendix E of *Software Abstractions* has a model of Hotel Operations. The model has an **assert** named **NoIntruder**. The assert is evaluated with this command:

```
check NoIntruder for 6 but 12 Time, 3 Room, 3 Guest
```

Is there a way to find the number of cases that the Alloy Analyzer considers in its evaluation of the **check** command? Does this message from the Analyzer indicate the number of cases?

```
Executing "Check NoIntruder for 6 but 12 Time, 3 Room, 3 Guest"
   Solver=sat4j Bitwidth=0 MaxSeq=0 SkolemDepth=1 Symmetry=20
   38549 vars. 921 primary vars. 76238 clauses. 90ms.
   No counterexample found. Assertion may be valid. 2914ms.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "considers". In the broadest sense, the state space of the search is 2^v, where v is the number of boolean variables -- in this case 38,459. Of course the SAT analyzer does not need to search that entire space, even if no instance is found, due to pruning.